# Dynamically set currency on Laravel Cashier 10 (Laravel 6.x)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-cashier

I have an application where admin can change the currency from the backend panel. As now cashier 10 has no `useCurrency()` method like older versions. What could be the way to set currency other than configuring the `.env` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite config used by laravel cashier.

i.e

```
config(['cashier.currency'=> 'EUR']);
```

You can also verify after updating the config.

```
$currency = config('cashier.currency');
```

You can verify that config here in billable trait being used.

https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/10.0/src/Billable.php#L793